# Eclipse XML graphic issues when modifying Android layouts

Tags: android, eclipse

I've had this issue for a very long time through multiple installs and projects. I've tried searching to no avail and I've managed to work around it but it's finally irritated me to *almost certain death*...

**I'm running the latest version of ADT on Eclipse 3.7.2 on Windows 7 x64 with Oracle JDK 1.7.0_05**

What happens is that after editing a layout in the graphical WYSIWYG-ish editor and setting a TextView to some text, when I switch to the text/XML view I have the following happen:

[image: Screenshot 1]

As you can see, there's the closing tag for LinearLayout at the bottom without a line number. For some reason, the text editor offsets all visible text by one line. If I highlight it, it corrects itself *sometimes* and only partially:

[image: Screenshot 2]

Is anyone else having this issue? I can't be the only one. Thanks

**Edit:** Tried Eclipse 4.2, same issue.

[image: Screenshot 3]

Comment: Have seen that too, but Idk a solution other than using Ubuntu where it works fine for me. But I haven't looked for a way to solve it tbh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I most definitely have this issue, after making changes in the graphical editor too.

I've found that if you select all, delete with a backspace then undo, it resolves itself. It happens so much I have the shortcuts down to nothing more than an inconvenience now

<s>**Edit:** Ok, so the problem is Eclipse 3.7. Updating to 4.2 has fixed this for me.</s>

It appears not. For me, the glitch seems to occur only when changing an attribute of a view using the WYSIWYG editor

Comment: Now that you mention it, I remember trying that out and it working but I'm looking for a more permanent solution.

Comment: Ok, So I too have been using Eclipse 3.7, and I've been putting off updating it for a while.
In light of fixing this problem, I updated to 4.2 to see if it's an IDE issue and as it turns out, it is. Since updating, the problem has disappeared. Good luck!

Comment: After I posted this question yesterday, I tried it in Eclipse 4.2. Issue is still there. See third screenshot I put up.

Comment: I'm going to accept this answer even though it isn't a permanent fix. I have taken kcoppock's suggestion though and switched to IntelliJ. I appreciate the speed improvement over Eclipse and the non-glitchy behavior of this new IDE.